# How to put images in particle explosions using CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to put cookies doing a particle explosion and I need to replace the particles with an image, I already tried to do background-image but doesn't work.

```
$d: 20px;

html { overflow: hidden; background: #222; }

.particle {
    position: absolute;
    width: $d; height: $d;
    animation: shoot 3s ease-out infinite;
    animation-name: shoot, fade;
    border-radius: 50px;
    
    @for $i from 0 to 50 {
        $t: (1 + .01*random(50))*1s;
        
        &:nth-child(#{$i + 1}) {
            transform: translate(random(100)*1vw, 
                                                     random(100)*1vh);
            background: hsl(random(360), 100%, 65%);
            animation-duration: $t;
            animation-delay: -.01*random(100)*$t;
        }
    }
}

@keyframes shoot {
    0% { transform: translate(50vw, 50vh); }
}
@keyframes fade { to { opacity: 0 } }
```

This is how looks like:
[image]

Comment: `I already tried to do background-image` how? Also, it'd better for set a tag of which css preprocessor you are using. Also2, it'd be even better if you can create a **working** snippet using the built-in snippet or with jsbin.com, codepan etc.

Comment: I already solve it by doing this in html: <img class="particle" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/848193695516721152/864142674542067722/bolachaSBG.png">

Comment: @otaner Your link doesn't do anything.  Would have been nice to show in the 'Answer' section how you solved it.  Welcome to Stackoverflow.